# failed to create bar error in ibm command console

Tags: apache

i am getting below error when trying to create a bar using this command

Command: D:\ApacheAnt\apache-ant-1.9.7-bin\apache-ant-1.9.7\bin\ant -f build.xml

Error: D:\Ant Build and Deployment Scripts\AntBuild\Scripts>D:\ApacheAnt\apache-ant-1.9.7-bin\apache-ant-1.9.7\bin\ant -f build.xml
    Buildfile: D:\Ant Build and Deployment Scripts\AntBuild\Scripts\build.xml

```
runScript:

buildWorkspace:
     [echo] The applications [MF_HTB_B1_HTTPSOAPINPUT] will be checkout from SVN
 under the URL [https://punitp134088l.ad.infosys.com/svn/ESB_Rep/branches/ESB_Fr
ameWork/ESB_FRAMEWORK/CODE_BASE/HTTP%20Based%20Framework/MF_HTB_B1]
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Ant Build and Deployment Scripts\AntBuild\BuildPacka
ge\tempWorkspace\MF_HTB_B1_HTTPSOAPINPUT

svnCheckout:
     [echo] Checking-out MF_HTB_B1_HTTPSOAPINPUT from SVN
      [svn] <Checkout> started ...
      [svn] Command completed abnormally.
      [svn] <Checkout> finished.
     [echo] Checkout completed

buildBarfiles:
     [echo] Compile and Create Bar files for [MF_HTB_B1_HTTPSOAPINPUT] applicati
ons
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Ant Build and Deployment Scripts\AntBuild\BuildPacka
ge\BarFiles
     [echo] D:\Ant Build and Deployment Scripts\AntBuild\Scripts
     [echo] Compiling Application [MF_HTB_B1_HTTPSOAPINPUT] for any errors
     [exec] Result: 1
   [delete] Deleting: D:\Ant Build and Deployment Scripts\AntBuild\BuildPackage\
Logs\MF_HTB_B1_HTTPSOAPINPUT.log
     [echo] Failed to create MF_HTB_B1_HTTPSOAPINPUT.bar, Please check ..\BuildP
ackage\Logs\BuildPackage.log for logs

applyBarOverride:
     [echo] Executing [mqsiapplybaroverride] for Application [MF_HTB_B1_HTTPSOAP
INPUT]

BUILD FAILED
D:\Ant Build and Deployment Scripts\AntBuild\Scripts\build.xml:42: The following
 error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Ant Build and Deployment Scripts\AntBuild\Scripts\build.xml:175: The followin
g error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Ant Build and Deployment Scripts\AntBuild\Scripts\build.xml:182: Execute fail
ed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mqsiapplybaroverride" (in directory
 "D:\Ant Build and Deployment Scripts\AntBuild\Scripts"): CreateProcess error=2,
 The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1059)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:629)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Jav
a13CommandLauncher.java:58)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:426)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:440)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:629)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:670)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:496)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.jav
a:396)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForDelegate.doSequentialIteration(ForDelegate
.java:228)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForDelegate.doTheTasks(ForDelegate.java:253)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForDelegate.execute(ForDelegate.java:213)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.For.execute(For.java:166)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(Single
CheckExecutor.java:38)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)

        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
cutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:854)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find th
e file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:397)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:148)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1040)
        ... 62 more

Total time: 10 seconds
```

i am running a command to execute ant script. Command: D:\ApacheAnt\apache-ant-1.9.7-bin\apache-ant-1.9.7\bin\ant -f build.xml this is for creating a bar file using apache ant s/w. Build.xml ant script is used to create a BuildPackage.zip file and include the bar files, deployment scripts and environment specific property files into it. but not able to create the bar. Getting above error.
Please assist.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, please edit your question to provide more information such as what is it you are trying to achieve and what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to create a .jar file using ant script, try to use JDK as installed JRE in eclipse(if you have), and to set the JAVA-HOME variable to JDK path.